# Perl: Replace text parameter by current timestamp

Tags: perl, replace, timestamp

I have an utility to generate code documentation every night. I would like to add a timestamp in order to be aware how old the generated documentation is. I would like to use perl.

I've seen that with the following sentence I can change a joker (%1) by any value I want

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/%1/date/g' footer.html
```

And with this other one I can get the system timestamp:

```
perl -MPOSIX -we "print POSIX::strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', localtime)"
```

My question is whether there is any way to merge both instructions in just one sentence.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
perl -MPOSIX -pi.bak -e 'BEGIN{$date = strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime);} s/%1/$date/g' file.html
```

Answer (score 3):

`sh` command:

```
perl -i.bak -MPOSIX -pe's/%1/strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime)/eg'
```

`cmd` command:

```
perl -i.bak -MPOSIX -pe"s/%1/strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', localtime)/eg"
```

`/e` cause the replacement expression to be treated as Perl code to execute, the result of which is the replacement text.